# Magento : product option div

Tags: magento

i have a product with size and color options (configurable product), in the product page the option r shown but i do wanna display it like the img bellow :

[image]

how can i do that using magento admin ?

Comment: souf,you want to show  it corresponding image

Comment: @AmitBera i have the same div but its displayed under "More views" but i wanna display it like in the image

Comment: you want this work as like http://www.seventyeightpercent.com/shop/gustav-messenger-bag-japanese-cotton-canvas-italian-vegetable-tanned-leather.html

Answer (score 0):

thats the real probleme its simple just how to change the red one to brown :

[image]